# Is there more efficient way to find a line of same items in a list matrix?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm making a "Tic-Tac-Toe" program in python, and trying to check whether or not a player got a winning "Three in a row" move. I have a method, but I don't know if it's good or if it can be shortened.

Here is my code:

```
board = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]]
winner = 0

def checkIfWon(player):
    #check rows
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == player:
            winner = player
    #check columns
    for i in range(3):
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == player:
            winner = player
    #check diagonals
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == player:
        winner = player
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == player:
        winner = player

runGame = True

while runGame:
    (Game Loop)
    checkIfWon(1)
    checkIfWon(2)
```

Comment: What about testing for a sum of 3, along each axis?

Comment: ill ttry something like. that I'll try a sum of 6 or 3, put in list, and check if 3 in list or 6 in list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to you want "efficient" as in short code, not necessarily micro-optimized for performance. So let's go with this:

We can compare lists for equality. So let's start by building the winning pattern; 3 entries listing player.

```py
def checkIfWon(player):
    winning = [player] * 3
```

Now we can simply compare each row. But we cannot compare column-wise. However, transposing the matrix is simple.

```py
    transposed = [list(col) for col in zip(*board)]
```

The diagonals are a bit more tedious but the iteration pattern and `reversed` help.

```py
    diag1 = [row[col] for col, row in enumerate(board)]
    diag2 = [row[col] for col, row in enumerate(reversed(board))]
```

Now we can just search for a match:

```py
    if winning in board or winning in transposed or winning in (diag1, diag2):
        winner = player
```

Side-note:
You seem to want to change a global variable `winner` but you don't declare it global in your function. Either do the clean thing and just return the winner, or declare `global winner` inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify some parts of it a bit, but this is an ugly one in general, so the improvements are modest.

One change is to compare `list`s as a whole for the row test, changing:

```
for i in range(3):
    if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == player:
```

to:

```
if [player]*3 in board:
```

For columns, you can't simplify it that much, but you can still write a slightly cleaner test, changing:

```
if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == player:
```

to:

```
if [row[i] for row in board] == [player]*3:
```

The improvements for the diagonals are even less useful, but you can simplify a *little*:

```
if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == player:
    winner = player
if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == player:
    winner = player
```

becomes the (arguably) improved:

```
if board[1][1] == player and (board[0][0] == board[2][2] == player or board[0][2] == board[2][0] == player):
```

which is improved solely insofar as it short-circuits when the center isn't held by the player (preventing either diagonal from working).

One thing that would help here is if you represented the board as a single contiguous `list`, rather than multidimensional, allowing slicing to do more work, and making the tests simple enough to fold them into an `any` test with a generator expression, rather than a `for` loop with `if` test. If the board were a length `9` `list`, the tests could simplify to:

```
threeinarow = [player]*3  # Make the three element list just once
# Row tests
if any(board[row*3:row*3+3] == threeinarow for row in range(3)):
    winner = player

if any(board[col::3] == threeinarow for col in range(3))
    winner = player

# Test top-left to bottom-right diagonal and top-right to bottom left diagonal
if board[::4] == threeinarow or board[2:8:2] == threeinarow:
    winner = player
```

But I must admit the magic numbers in the diagonals test make me uneasy, so it's not a pure improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It can be nicely written if you are willing to use `numpy.array` instead of built-in lists (which I fully understand you may not). Basically by using vectorised `all` and `any` on both axes:

```
import numpy as np

board = np.array([
    [1,1,2],
    [0,1,2],
    [2,1,1]
])
winner = 0

def checkIfWon(player):
    if np.any(np.all(board == player, axis=0)):
        return True
    return np.any(np.all(board == player, axis=1))


print(checkIfWon(1))
print(checkIfWon(2))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: You're missing the diagonals. Checking `np.diag(board)` and `np.diag(board[::-1])` fixes that